# How do you ban a person from your clan?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have a player that was in our clan. We kicked him out but he keeps coming back. How do you ban a player? We changed the settings to Closed clan and Invite Only clan and we even erased trophies. Nothing is working.

Comment: Who's inviting him back? Chances are one of his friends is still in the clan and keeps reinviting him.

Comment: Wish we could find that out. The only way I know of demote everyone to members and kick that kid out. Then members regain our respect evwn though only one is doing it probably

Answer (score 5):

The only explanation is that someone is inviting him. I would recommend demoting everyone but yourself down to member and letting it blow over. Then give back everyone's rank. This should discourage anyone from inviting him again.

It sounds extreme, but it is the only way next to disbanding your clan.

Also, There is no such thing as 'banning' someone from your clan. When you kick them out, they get a message when they try to join saying: You have been banned from this clan. However, they can just join the next day(24 hours). I would recommend changing your clan entry status to invite only too, that way you can reject his request if he was to make one.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you change the clan to 'Closed' that way there is no way he can get in, unless his friend is a co-leader.

Answer (score 1):

If u met him in Global, report him! Also, muting him will stop him from joining. It worked for me!